# np.shuffle much slower than np.random.choice

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of shape (N, 3) and I'd like to randomly shuffle the rows. N is on the order of 100,000.

I discovered that np.random.shuffle was bottlenecking my application. I tried replacing the shuffle with a call to np.random.choice and experienced a 10x speed-up. What's going on here? Why is it so much faster to call np.random.choice? Does the np.random.choice version generate a uniformly distributed shuffle?

```
import timeit

task_choice = '''
N = 100000
x = np.zeros((N, 3))
inds = np.random.choice(N, N, replace=False)
x[np.arange(N), :] = x[inds, :]
'''

task_shuffle = '''
N = 100000
x = np.zeros((N, 3))
np.random.shuffle(x)
'''

task_permute = '''
N = 100000
x = np.zeros((N, 3))
x = np.random.permutation(x)
'''

setup = 'import numpy as np'

timeit.timeit(task_choice, setup=setup, number=10)
>>> 0.11108078400138766

timeit.timeit(task_shuffle, setup=setup, number=10)
>>> 1.0411593900062144

timeit.timeit(task_permute, setup=setup, number=10)
>>> 1.1140159380011028
```

Edit: For anyone curious, I decided to go with the following solution since it is readable and outperformed all other methods in my benchmarks:

```
task_ind_permute = '''
N = 100000
x = np.zeros((N, 3))
inds = np.random.permutation(N)
x[np.arange(N), :] = x[inds, :]
'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`permutation`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/18f2385b29bdd62701a1a82d7bf33fd87430a05e/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx#L4865) and [`shuffle`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/18f2385b29bdd62701a1a82d7bf33fd87430a05e/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx#L4777) are linked, in fact `permutation` calls `shuffle` under the hood!!

The reason why `shuffle` is slower than `permutation` for multidimensional array is that `permutation` only need to `shuffle` the index along the first axis. Thus becomes a special case of `shuffle` of 1d array (the 1st if-else block).

This special case is also explained in the source as well:

```
# We trick gcc into providing a specialized implementation for
# the most common case, yielding a ~33% performance improvement.
# Note that apparently, only one branch can ever be specialized.
```

For `shuffle` on the otherhand,  multidimensional ndarray operation requires a bounce buffer, creating that buffer, especially when the dimension is relative big, becomes expensive.  Additionally, we can no longer use the trick mentioned above that helps the 1d case.

With `replace=False` and using `choice` to generate a new array of the same size, `choice` and `permutation` is the same, see [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/18f2385b29bdd62701a1a82d7bf33fd87430a05e/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx#L1189). The extra time would have to come from the time spend in creating intermediate index arrays.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and especially for linking to the source code proving that choice calls permutation. One thing that's a bit confusing is that the docs seem to suggest that both shuffle and permutation act only along first axis for multidimensional arrays.

shuffle: "This function only shuffles the array along the first axis of a multi-dimensional array.axis."

permutation: "If x is a multi-dimensional array, it is only shuffled along its first index."

In short, for my application where I need to shuffle the rows, is there any reason for me not to use the np.random.choice method?

Answer (score 2):

You're comparing *very* different sized arrays here. In your first example, although you create an array of zeros, you simply use `random.choice(100000, 100000)`, which pulls 100000 random values between 1-100000.  In your second example your are shuffling a `(100000, 3)` shape array.

```
>>> x.shape
(100000, 3)
>>> np.random.choice(N, N, replace=False).shape
(100000,)
```

Timings on more equivalent samples:

```
In [979]: %timeit np.random.choice(N, N, replace=False)
2.6 ms ± 201 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [980]: x = np.arange(100000)

In [981]: %timeit np.random.shuffle(x)
2.29 ms ± 67.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [982]: x.shape == np.random.choice(N, N, replace=False).shape
Out[982]: True
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Yes, of course the indices are of a different shape since they correspond only to the first dimension of the array into which I'm indexing. I think maybe you didn't notice that after generating the indices I'm using them to perform a shuffle? My question is "why use np.random.shuffle when it seems you can shuffle 10x faster using indices from np.random.choice?".